# How can I exploit this vulnerable SQL statement I found on this web server

Tags: sql, webserver, mariadb, sql-injection, penetration-testing

I just encountered a really simple but rather complicated SQL query which executes on validating the username in MariaDB. The statement has two escape charecters and I cant seem to get around that. I have been trying different payload but none of them seem to work. On a invalid statement it returns a traceback Call error informing about the error.

I have already tried 1' or '1'='1 and the 0 version of this

```
python
    if cur.execute('SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=\'%s\'' % request.form['username'].replace('%', '%%')) == 0:
```

I wanted to find a way to bypass this validation statement and grant me access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind such practice on websites you do not own/have the owner consent is illegal.

Try with and Union, the input:

```
' and 1=2 UNION SELECT 'anypass' --
```

would produce the following query if I understood your problem correctly:

```
SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username='' and 1=2 UNION SELECT 'anypass' --
```

Union operator requires the same number of columns, if you get an error of that type, try with the following:

```
' and 1=2 UNION SELECT 'anypass', null --
```

Add null columns until you no longer have an error.

Then you only have to put 'anypass' in the password field.

Comment: nope not working... IT has error at the expression '''